# Incorrect FrameLayout's childs order on android 5.0 and above

Tags: android, android-framelayout, xml-layout

Here is my XML layout code:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_test"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_test"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

As I expected the `TextView` will overlay on the `Button`, but it only working on android < 5.0. I research for all API changes about `FrameLayout` from developer site but still not getting exactly information. Did anyone find that? How to overlay `TextView` on `Button` via XML?

Comment: what is the result on 5+ devices?

Comment: @pskink , The result is the `TextView` not overlayed on `Button`.

Comment: since it was hard to believe that such a change could be introduced on 5+ API i took your layout, tested on 5.0.1 and everything works as expected

Comment: @pskink, well, I have tested this issue on nexus 6 with 5.1, nexus 9 with 6.0 and emulator (gennymotion) with 5.0. all of them got problem. That why I asked here.

Comment: what do you see in hierarchyviewer? what is the order of child views of your `FrameLayout`?

Comment: The order is :
(0) `FrameLayout`
    (0) `Button`
    (1) `TextView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I known the change. That is `evelation` . Hope this help other.  http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the correct answer for your question but for current development what I can suggest is the layout you require.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_test"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_test"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="12"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have change `Button` with other views (`ImageButton, ImageView, FrameLayout....`), the `TextView` is overlayed on it. So, seem it's only not working with `Button`. @@

Comment: I tried to read about it in meantime and what I deduced ( In my mind ! ) that button has its other layer (that is being shown when we click it) and that contains its own z-layer. And that layer messes with our frame layout.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar Sheth, Maybe you're right, but how about other views such as `ImageButton`, `ImageView`, `View`,...why don't they have your mentioned layer?

Answer (score 1):

Add `stateListAnimator="@null"` to your Button XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_test"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null" />

        ...

</FrameLayout>
```

This will make the `Button` respect its Z-index and position it under the `TextView`.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html)

Comment: This helped me solve a problem applying a third party `BadgeView` that added itself and a target button into a `FrameLayout`. The button just refused to appear beneath the badge until making the XML change here.

Answer (score 0):

It's addition to @John answer. You can do something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_test"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_test"
        ...
        android:elevation="20dp"
        ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

And then in code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        finfViewById(R.id.tv_test).setOutlineProvider(null);
}
```